# iOS Lock event delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I want to give a push notification from a closed app when the the user locks the screen. How would I get a call do so and is it possible without the application being open?

I've seen suggestions of implementing `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` in your app delegate, but would that work even if the app wasn't open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app can receive some notifications but as shannoga said, there's no global notification for the screen.

An iOS app can be in one of these states ([from here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)):

> **Not running**
> The app has not been launched or was running but was
> terminated by the system.
>
> **Inactive**
> The app is running in the
> foreground but is currently not receiving events. (It may be executing
> other code though.) An app usually stays in this state only briefly as
> it transitions to a different state.
>
> **Active**
> The app is running in the foreground and is receiving events. This is
> the normal mode for foreground apps.
>
> **Background**
> The app is in the
> background and executing code. Most apps enter this state briefly on
> their way to being suspended. However, an app that requests extra
> execution time may remain in this state for a period of time. In
> addition, an app being launched directly into the background enters
> this state instead of the inactive state. For information about how to
> execute code while in the background, see “Background Execution and
> Multitasking.”
>
> **Suspended**
> The app is in the background but is not
> executing code. The system moves apps to this state automatically and
> does not notify them before doing so. While suspended, an app remains
> in memory but does not execute any code. When a low-memory condition
> occurs, the system may purge suspended apps without notice to make
> more space for the foreground app.

[image: iOS application states]

If you want to get more info on the application states and what notifications are sent when the app transitions from one state to another I would strongly suggest the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Comment: But hasnt apple been pushing for background refreshing and things of that sort? Is there anything in that area that would allow something like what I am thinking of?

Comment: When an app goes into background apple want's you to use as little of the system resources as possible. One of the bullet points in the "Being a Responsible Background App" is to "Do minimal work while running in the background". Your app could go into background from a number of reasons: phone call, home button touched, lock screen etc. You are only notified that the app will enter background, and not the reason that for which this happens

Comment: When you say 'background', you mean multitasking, right? Not completely quit?

Comment: I dont want the user to have to leave the app open. Just to get these notifications, even when the app is completely closed, when they lock their homescreen

Comment: What about something like a silent push notification? http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/ That is sent periodically, keeping the app alive during a set period of the day so it can send local push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want your app to know that the user shouted of the iPhone screen even if your app is killed or in background ?

If so then I am a afraid you can not do that.

-applicationDidEnterBackground is called to your app when it is alive and going to background. There is no global notification the the user locks the iPhone screen.

If you could explain what do you want to achieve it might be easier to help you.

Comment: I want to give a local push notification every time the screen is locked and then remove it when the screen is unlocked, 'persistent' push notifications